# sum up rows based on row.names and condition in col.names -- R

Tags: r, dataframe, sum

```
df <- data.frame(row.names = c('1s.u1','1s.u2','2s.u1','2s.u2','6s.u1'),fjri_deu_klcea= c('0','0','0','15','23'),hfue_klcea=c('2','2','0','156','45'),dji_dhi_ghcea_jk=c('456','0','0','15','15'),jdi_jdi_ghcea=c('1','2','3','4','100'),gz7_jfu_dcea_jdi=c('5','6','3','7','56'))

df
      fjri_deu_klcea hfue_klcea dji_dhi_ghcea_jk jdi_jdi_ghcea gz7_jfu_dcea_jdi
1s.u1              0          2              456             1                5
1s.u2              0          2                0             2                6
2s.u1              0          0                0             3                3
2s.u2             15        156               15             4                7
6s.u1             23         45               15           100               56
```

I want to sum up `df` based on the `cea` part of the column names. So all rows with the same `cea` part should sum up.
`df` should look like this

```
        klcea      ghcea            dcea
1s.u1      2         457               5
1s.u2      2          2                6
2s.u1      0          3                3
2s.u2      171        19               7
6s.u1      68         115              56
```

I thought about firstly getting a new column with the `cea` name called `cea` and then summing it up based on `row.names` and the respective `cea`
with something like `with(df, ave(cea, row.names(df), FUN = sum))`

I do not know how to generate the new column based on a pattern in a string. I guess `grepl` is useful but I could not come up with something, I tried `df$cea <- df[grepl(colnames(df),'cea'),]` which is wrong...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using base R, you can extract the "cea" part from the name and use it in `split.default` to split dataframe into columns, we can then use `rowSums` to sum each individual dataframe.

```
sapply(split.default(df, sub('.*_(.*cea).*', '\\1', names(df))), rowSums)

#      dcea ghcea klcea
#1s.u1    5   457     2
#1s.u2    6     2     2
#2s.u1    3     3     0
#2s.u2    7    19   171
#6s.u1   56   115    68
```

where `sub` part returns :

```
sub('.*_(.*cea).*', '\\1', names(df))
#[1] "klcea" "klcea" "ghcea" "ghcea" "dcea"
```

Answer (score 1):

Using dplyr:

```
> df %>% rowwise() %>% mutate(klcea = sum(c_across(ends_with('klcea'))), 
+                             ghcea = sum(c_across(contains('ghcea'))),
+                             dcea = sum(c_across(contains('dcea')))) %>% 
+                     select(klcea, ghcea, dcea)
# A tibble: 5 x 3
# Rowwise: 
  klcea ghcea  dcea
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     2   457     5
2     2     2     6
3     0     3     3
4   171    19     7
5    68   115    56
```

If you wish to retain row names:

```
> df %>% rownames_to_column('rn') %>% rowwise() %>% mutate(klcea = sum(c_across(ends_with('klcea'))), 
+                             ghcea = sum(c_across(contains('ghcea'))),
+                             dcea = sum(c_across(contains('dcea')))) %>% 
+                     select(klcea, ghcea, dcea, rn) %>% column_to_rownames('rn')
      klcea ghcea dcea
1s.u1     2   457    5
1s.u2     2     2    6
2s.u1     0     3    3
2s.u2   171    19    7
6s.u1    68   115   56
>
```